# подключение под root к VPS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, vps, root

Всем доброго времени суток. Недавно приобрел *VPS (ubuntu 16.04 LTS)* и сейчас разбираюсь с ним. Поставил туда OpenVPN и ufw, И после данных действий не подключается под root (ни к серверу, ни через FileZillaк данным). В ufw порт разрешен,в настройках ssh *PermitRootLogin* в значение *yes*. Даже пытался в sshd_config добавить **AllowUsers root**, и все равно не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста,в чем еще может быть проблема? Интересны абсолютно все (адекватные) версии. Я просто уже не знаю,в какую сторону копать.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: запусти ssh -vvv ...

Comment: А что должно быть после запуска данной команды? Пока она не очень помогла :)

Comment: телнетом цепляется?

Comment: должно показать почему не подключается

Comment: @eri а показал только список приставок, которые могу использовать, и в самом начале сообщения начало ssh ключа.

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev Даже не знаю, что это,так что вряд ли :)

Comment: @МишаковАлександр с Unix не работали как я понял. ставте PuTTy на винду и *прочтите* мануал. полная строка команды: ssh user@host -vvv

Comment: @Hellseher, да, вы правы. опыт работы с Unix очень маленький,вот и пытаюсь разобраться. PuTTy стоит, мануал прочту, хорошо. Просто вопрос был задан с целью разобраться *с ним* сейчас.